# Load image in device independent and screen independent fashion into a layout view using 1.6 SDK

Tags: android, image, scale

I'm having trouble getting an asset image to scale up when I load it. The new call to BitmapDrawable(Resources, BitmapDrawable) is not available on 1.6 SDK. 
Is there a workaround to load the BitmapDrawable the old way and then somehow manipulate it? I have tried calling setTargetDensity() to no avail. My code (which doesn't scale properly) is:

> ```
>     ImageView iv = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.image);
>  iv.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(view.getContext().getAssets().open(path)));
> ```

Comment: Adding the word "android" to your question would have helped :)

Answer (score 5):

I found a way that worked, after doing some good old RTFM.
The following code works:

> ```
>   ImageView iv = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.image);
>     BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
>     opts.inScaled = true;
>     opts.inDensity = DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM;
>     Rect padding = new Rect();
>     opts.inTargetDensity = view.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
>     Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(view.getContext().getAssets().open(path), padding, opts);
>     iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
> ```
>
> For background see http://d.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html